# Show custom menus in seven theme

Tags: navigation

I am using Seven for the theme of a internal application. I have custom items setup in the mainmenu, but cannot get it to show?!?!

The blocks for seven are limited to content and help (despite the .info file suggesting a few more???).

```
/admin/structure/menu/settings
```

I have set main menu to both Main and Secondary links.

```
/admin/appearance/settings
```

I have checked both main and secondary links

What am I missing? How do I get he mainmenu (or any menu) to show in the default Seven theme (without deriving a new theme from it and tweaking it's template.php, etc)???

I can do this with any other default theme...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid that Seven's `page.tpl.php` does not render these menus. You will need to subtheme it and modify `tpl.php` files to render the menus. I know you stated that you want to avoid this; however, you really should do this anyway because if you are using the theme in your app then you will at some point likely want to modify it in some way, and you don't want to customize a core theme because it will break on updates, etc.

It's worth it, because Seven is actually a great theme for internal web apps (I use it for this).

Seven's navigation was meant to be provided by Drupal's tab system. I suggest rendering your main menu and secondary menu as tabs to leverage the navigational design of Seven.

Comment: Ya I see that it renders $primary_local_tasks which are initialized in the preprocess hooks. The preprocess hooks (in my derived theme) are what would initialize primary_local_tasks with the data from mainmenu or secondary menu, correct?

Answer (score 1):

You can render menu using blocks system. Just enable "Main menu" block in the "Seven" theme.
See my screenshot:

[image]

To style your menu with icons you can use the [menu_attributes](https://drupal.org/project/menu_attributes) module. You can add css class to each menu and style it with CSS.

Also mind that changing theme source code it not a good way. You should create a subtheme of "Seven".

Comment: The problem is Seven only has two visible regions - content and help - neither of which is where I wanted my menu...